# What would explain the difference in running times of these two Java programs?

Tags: java, visitor-pattern

I've two simple pieces of Java code. Both implement the same functionality.

The first version uses Visitor pattern while the second version relocates code to remove double dispatch. I thought the 2nd version should run faster. But, the first one is faster by 10% on several runs. How can this be explained? Is it not the right way to benchmark this?

The corner cases are not handled well (not the concern here) and append is intentionally not done in constant time (I want to maximise the number of double dispatches).

Sample 1 (Visitor) :

```
interface List {
    public void accept(Visitor v);
}

interface Visitor {
    public void visit(Nil x);
    public void visit(Cons x);
}

class Nil implements List {
    public void accept(Visitor v) {
        v.visit(this);
    }
}

class Cons implements List {
    public int head;
    public List tail;
    public Cons(int d, List l) {
        this.head = d;
        this.tail = l;
    }

    public void accept(Visitor v) {
        v.visit(this);
    }
}

class Append implements Visitor {
    Cons prev;
    int data;
    public Append (int d) {
        this.data = d;
    }

    public void visit(Nil x) {
        Cons n = new Cons(this.data, x);
        prev.tail = n;
    }

    public void visit(Cons x) {
        this.prev = x;
        x.tail.accept(this);
    }
}

public class ListVisBenchmark {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int TEST_SIZE = 20000;
        Cons l;

        long t1 = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            l = new Cons(0, new Nil());
            for (int j = 0; j < TEST_SIZE; j++) {
                l.accept(new Append(j));
            }
        }
        long t2 = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Exec : " + ((t2-t1)*1e-6) + " ms");
    }
}
```

Sample 2 (Alternate) :

```
interface List {
    public void __Append__(Append v);
}

interface Visitor {
}

class Nil implements List {
    public void __Append__(Append v) {
        Cons n = new Cons(v.data, this);
        v.prev.tail = n;
    }
}

class Cons implements List {
    public int head;
    public List tail;
    public Cons(int d, List l) {
        this.head = d;
        this.tail = l;
    }

    public void __Append__(Append v) {
        v.prev = this;
        this.tail.__Append__(v);
    }
}

class Append implements Visitor{
    Cons prev;
    int data;
    public Append (int d) {
        this.data = d;
    }
}

public class ListOptBenchmark {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int TEST_SIZE = 20000;
        Cons l;

        long t1 = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            l = new Cons(0, new Nil());
            for (int j = 0; j < TEST_SIZE; j++) {
                l.__Append__(new Append(j));
            }
        }
        long t2 = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println("Exec : " + ((t2-t1)*1e-6) + " ms");

    }
}
```

Output of each of these programs :

```
$ java ListVisBenchmark
Exec : 7500.791179 ms

$ java ListOptBenchmark
Exec : 8183.261969 ms
```

Multiple runs give nearly similar results. Always, Vis < Opt

Comment: Can you share the output from your test runs as well?

Comment: If you didn't run each a few tens of millions of times so that JIT was nice and warmed up then any benchmarks are invalid.  Search the web for "java micro benchmark" to learn why this is _really hard_ to do right.

Comment: I'll look into it. Sample 2 is how we normally add functionality to classes. I'm more stumped by the fact that there is a more obscure (visitor) way of writing code which is readily optimised by jvm.